# If two fields are isomorphic then so are their algebraic closures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $E,F$ are isomorphic fields, is it always true that $\bar E\cong \bar F$?

Now suppose $f:E\to F$ is an isomorphism, I want to construct an isomorphism $f':\bar E\to \bar F$ based on $f$. If this is possible, how should I start?

Comment: Check out the isomorphism extension theorem, it does what you want.

Comment: @Charlie thanks. This is of much help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the proof that the algebraic closure is unique up to isomorphism? This is essentially what you're asking, since given an algebraic closure $j: F\rightarrow\overline{F}$ of $F$ and an isomorphism $\alpha: E\rightarrow F$, we can view $\overline{F}$ as an algebraic closure of $E$.

Comment: Actually the proof is beyond my course's level and is attached at the end of the chapter as an appendix. But I'll surely check on that. Thanks for your help.